# Calling create_envelope api gives INVALID_USERID error

Tags: docusignapi

I am using

```
token = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(client_id=self.integration_key, user_id=self.user_id,
        expires_in=3600,
        oauth_host_name=self.oauth_host_name,
        private_key_bytes=private_key,
        scopes=(OAuth.SCOPE_SIGNATURE, OAuth.SCOPE_IMPERSONATION))
user_info = api_client.get_user_info(token.access_token)
self.base_path = user_info.accounts[0].base_uri + "/restapi" ## tested with and 
                                                  #without /restapi same result
```

to retrieve access token successfully and I also get the base uri successfully but when I create and send envelop using.

```
envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi(self.init_client())
envelopes_api.host = self.base_path #tested by explicitly assigning again and 
                                    # without this explicit assignment as well
welcome_letter_env = self._populate_template(template_id, signer_name, signer_email, subject, text_tabs, checkbox_tabs, radio_tabs)
results = envelopes_api.create_envelope(self.account_id, envelope_definition=welcome_letter_env)
```

I get INVALID_USERID error. Please note that the exact same code works smoothly for demo account this is happening only for production account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the base_uri to the correct value for your account.

See the results from the /oauth/userInfo call.

For example:

```
api_client = ApiClient()
api_client.host = base_path #### Setting the base path
api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + args["ds_access_token"])

envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
results = envelope_api.create_envelope(args["account_id"],
   envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
```

Comment: Already did that I've called the api_client.get_user_info(token.access_token) to set the base path. I'll update the question for it to be more elaborate.

Comment: as it turns out this actually was the main issue, I was updating the envelopapi.host instead I had to update the api_client.host. @Larry for quick response.

Comment: Glad to help @MuhammadShoaib. Thank you for the check.